# Overriding existing (untagged) table styles using CSS?

Tags: css

So. I'm a CSS amateur, and I'm dealing with an issue a bit above my experience.

Basically: we have a site with a third-party vendor. We cannot modify their stylesheet. I've been told we cannot forward the URL. We cannot unpublish the without deleting it, which is not an option. We cannot upload our own stylesheet. We cannot edit the page HTML beyond a small window. And we need to disable the the site-- specifically, login functions-- so users can't use it, and provide them a link to the new site.

tldr; If this sounds backwards and convoluted, please understand I'm just doing my best to work with a third-party that doesn't really have a lot of flexibility.

So far, I've done this by identifying the styles they have, and writing my own css to disable them (just setting everything to height:0px width:0px overflow:hidden has worked pretty okay) and inputting that into the text/html field they let me edit. Which, honestly, seems kind of like a design flaw that I can break any page as badly as I'm doing, but what do I know...

Problem: they have a login form in a table. No div or class associated with it. With no class/id, I can't style it through css. Styling "table" to height:0px, width:0px just, uh, blanks the whole page.

So, my question: how do I style a table with no class/id in CSS alone with no ability to add a tag to it?

And yes. I know what I'm doing is probably giving everyone reading it an aneurysm. I'm sorry for my CSS crimes.

Comment: So you are sorry for violating Stack Overflow's rules and policy but you'll do it anyway?

Comment: I, uh, missed that in the rules, and was being flippant? I'll delete this if so.

Comment: _And we need to disable the the site-- specifically, login functions-- so users can't use it, and provide them a link to the new site._ Don't change the file, but rather redirect links to your new website. You can do this in your server configuration

Comment: Hiding the form elements does not neccessarily prevent users from logging in

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: He asked how to target something with CSS, in need of an idea, not something in code to fix. People always bash those kind of questions but sometimes you only need a nudge towards idea, not specifications, code fix, references, performance advice or something specific. It's not the primary idea behind SO but it helped me immensely in my 1st year of development. I had Google but Google gives a lot and when you know a little it can be same as not giving you anything.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith He has a specific problem in a specific situation. The cascade of CSS  determines how to access elements and, without the markup, it's not possible how to access an element within the cascade. That is why markup needs to be provided; to prevent guesswork which creates too much back and forth to solve it as, invariably, a solution provided won't work in his unknown case.

Comment: I generally agree, but maybe with the knowledge he CAN use parents as part of selector, he can now create his own CSS selector. But you got a point, I even stated it's impossible to give correct solution without knowing the entire HTML structure. And even then a selector might leak to other pages.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith Yes, you get it, and that's exactly why the rule is posted, enforced, and this question will eventually get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the said form trough some parent which will work until they either reposition the table outside that parent or fuck with something you used to target the parent.

To be more specific I need a HTML structure of the said page. 
But generally let's say you find a parent with a class Parent and this is the only form (otherwise you have to say nth child of type form) inside that parent you can use `.Parent>form { your CSS code}`

This should expand options for you. Ideally find a parent somewhere that has id and hope its unique for site.

**NOTE: Be very afraid** when you target things like this, if you can't bind that to either that specific page or specific unique-for-site id parent, you risk somewhere being the one or multiple other match for your CSS selector, and since in most cases (unless you use CSS loader or have separate indexes including separate CSS files) you share same CSS to entire web page it will change them as well.

**NOTE: Be even more afraid** if you use CSS outside of it's domain - STYLING especcialy for security things, like giving access. This is a serious security violation if you only hide login elements. Anyone with a bit of knowledge can read the code and hide it on client and login. At least don't load then into DOM using `display:none;` instead `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: thanks. i know what i'm doing is BAD in all caps, but the limitations I have on what I'm capable of editing-- and my own skill!-- make it very difficult to do this in any kind of acceptable way.

Comment: I would try communicating my requests to those whom it may concern, you are partners after all or in some professional relationship? This is a poor man's choice for many reasons. Stability, maintainability, poor practice, possible security breaches..